# Adding Polyline through a timer on Google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, timer, location, polyline

I have a google map in which when user press 'start' button, a timer will start which will keep getting user's current location after every 10 seconds and will draw a polyline from previos to current location untill user hits the 'Stop tracking' button.
Now my is doing all fine except the polyline, it's not drawing the polyline thorugh a timer at all. And if i re-press the 'start' button it does ( add the poloyline from prev to current location, like my application will keep adding the polyline if i keep pressing start button but i don't want it this way). i want it to draw the line thorugh a timer not on the button press.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button start,stop,track_record;
    GPSTracker gps;
    ArrayList<String> cordsList= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
    ArrayList<Double> arrLat= new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> arrLng = new ArrayList<Double>();
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private final int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    double longitude,latitude;
    private static LatLng prev = new LatLng(0,0);
    int Flag = 0;
    static int begin = 0;
    private LatLng fixedBegin ;
    private LatLng listPoints = new LatLng(0,0);
    ArrayList<LatLng> listP= new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    Handler m_handler;
    Runnable m_handlerTask ;
    int t=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        track_record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_TR);




        // track record activity
        track_record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Your Tracking is started now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                                ///////*************************************////////
                                                // create class object
                                                gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);
                                                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                                                    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                                                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
                                                    @Override

                                                    public void run() {
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void run() {

                                                                LatLng current =   new LatLng(latitude = gps.getLatitude(),longitude = gps.getLongitude());

                                                                if (begin == 0) {
                                                               fixedBegin = current;

                                                                    // create marker
                                                                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(fixedBegin).title("Begin ");

                                                                    // Changing the color babyyy
                                                                  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                                                    // adding marker
                                                                mMap.addMarker(marker);

                                                                                                                                           // drawing polyline here


                                                                 if(Flag==0)  //when the first update comes, we have no previous points,hence this
                                                                    {
                                                                        prev=current;
                                                                        Flag=1;
                                                                    }
                                                                    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 16);
                                                                    mMap.animateCamera(update);
                                                                    mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                                                                            .add(prev, current).width(6).color(Color.BLUE)
                                                                            .visible(true));
                                                                    prev=current;
                                                                    current = null;



                                                              }
                                                                begin++;

                                                                Log.i("OK", "lat------ " + latitude);
                                                                Log.i("OK", "lng-------- " + longitude);

                                                                arrLat.add(latitude);
                                                                arrLng.add(longitude);



                                                                //////////// TRYING ///////////
                                                                // And it Worked :D

/*
                                                                if(Flag==0)  //when the first update comes, we have no previous points,hence this
                                                                {
                                                                    prev=current;
                                                                    Flag=1;
                                                                }
                                                                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 16);
                                                                mMap.animateCamera(update);
                                                                mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                                                                        .add(prev, current).width(6).color(Color.BLUE)
                                                                        .visible(true));
                                                                prev=current;
                                                                current = null;
*/


                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                    }
                                                }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);


                                                // check if GPS enabled
                                                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                                                    Log.i("ok", "Mai to hogaya true");
                                                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                                                    String longlat = String.valueOf(latitude) + ":" + String.valueOf(longitude);
                                                    cordsList.add(longlat);
                                                    // \n is for new line
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry cant get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    // can't get location
                                                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                                                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                                                    // gps.showSettingsAlert();
                                                }

                                                Log.i("Finall", "Location-> " + cordsList.toString());

                                            }
                                        }
        );

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Initializing
        MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Toast on stop
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Your Tracking is over now, yellow marker shows your destination", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /////////
                //yaha kaam karna hai abhi
                // create marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude())).title("REACHED :D ");

                // Changing the color babyyy
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                // adding marker
                mMap.addMarker(marker);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                timer.cancel();
            }

        });
    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                                       @Override
                                       public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                                           // Already two locations
                                           if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 1) {
                                               MarkerPoints.clear();
                                               mMap.clear();
                                           }

                                           // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                                           MarkerPoints.add(point);

                                           // Creating MarkerOptions
                                           MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                                           // Setting the position of the marker
                                           options.position(point);


                                           if (MarkerPoints.size() == 1) {
                                               options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                                           }
                                           // Below ELSE is not used any more due to the fetched location of user TADAAAA xD
                                           else if (MarkerPoints.size() == 2) {
                                               options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                           }


                                           // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                                           mMap.addMarker(options);


                                           // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                                           if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 1) {
                                               //>>>> LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
                                               LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                                               LatLng origin = latLng1;
                                               LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(0);

                                               // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                                               String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                                               Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                                               FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

                                               // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                                               FetchUrl.execute(url);
                                               //move map camera
                                               mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
                                               mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                                           }

                                       }
                                   }
        );


    }

    private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }


    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below two functions.

```
public void Draw_Map(List<LatLng> val) {
        if(val.size() > 1) {
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(val.get(mSource), val.get(mDestination))
                    .width(8)
                    .color(Color.BLACK));
            mSource++;
            mDestination++;
        }
}

private void drawFinalPolygon() {
        mLatLngList.add(mLatLngList.get(0));
        PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
        polygonOptions.addAll(mLatLngList);
        polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
        polygonOptions.strokeWidth(8);
        polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Polygon polygon = mGoogleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("Marker Title here")
                        .snippet("Hello, I am marker snippet!")
                        .position(mLatLngList.get(0)));
}
```

Call Draw_Map() method whenever the location changes and call drawFinalPolygon() method when user click on stop tracking.

Comment: Implement the Draw_Map() function inside your m_handlerTask handler where you are fetching location. Then draw the final polygon whenever you stop tracking.

Comment: hey i have edited my code please re-check, and sorry for the inconvience actually i have commented the handler code and have tried some thing different but i posted the wrong code here. 
The change is just only in the timer function with from Flag's condition please have a look !